# Redirect from login page using URL variable

Tags: php, ajax

I have a login page which which uses a Facebook login app to give users access to my website. Basically it works like this: There is a button called Login, which calls a function logIn() when clicked. This function makes a call to the Facebook API and a userID is obtained from Facebook. I then use ajax and POST that userID to the same page (login.php). Then once the userID is POSTED, the php part runs and at the end I invoke `exit("success")` which, is sent back to the AJAX call. In the `success` function I then redirect the user to the `index.php` page. An outline of the code is below:

The PHP part:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['userID'])) { //The userID is obtained from the FB API
    //Do many things
    exit("success"); //Sent as response to the AJAX call
  }
?>
```

The HTML part:

```
...
<button type="button" id="facebook-button" onclick="logIn()">Login</button>
...
```

The JavaScript part which obtains the userID and sets it:

```
<script>
  var person = { userID: "", name: ""};

  function logIn() {
            FB.login(function (response) {                
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    person.userID = response.authResponse.userID;              

                    FB.api('/me?fields=id, name, function (userData) {                        
                        person.name = userData.name;                        

                        $.ajax({
                           url: "login.php",
                           method: "POST",
                           data: person,
                           dataType: 'text',
                           success: function (serverResponse) {                               
                               if (serverResponse == "success"){                                   
                                   window.location = "index.php";                                  
                               }
                           }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }, {scope: 'public_profile'})
        }
</script>
```

OK, so this all work perfectly. Now, say I have a post somewhere on my website and for the user to be able to comment on the post, they have to be logged in. So I placed a button below that post:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' href='login.php?id=$submission_id' role='button'>Login</a>
```

As can be seen, the URL contains a URL variable (an integer called `$submission_id`) so the user will be redirected to `www.mywebsite.com/login.php?id=submission_id`.

The reason I am doing so is so that I can redirect the user back to the specific post after the user has logged in.

So I know I can obtain the URL variable using:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){                                                    
    $submission_id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

So my question is how can I send back and redirect the user to the post they were reading?

I tried doing something like this:

The PHP part:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['id'])){                                                    
    $submission_id = $_GET['id'];
  }
  else{
    $submission_id = 0;
  } 

  if (isset($_POST['userID'])) { //The userID is obtained from the FB API
    //Do many things

    if($submission_id==0){       
      exit("success");
    } else {
      header("Location: details.php?id=".$submission_id);
      exit;
    }
  }
?>
```

Which didn't work (probably because the ajax callback never receiver a reply (something like that?)

I also thought of something like this:

The PHP part:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['id'])){                                                    
    $submission_id = $_GET['id'];
  }
  else{
    $submission_id = 0;
  } 

  if (isset($_POST['userID'])) { //The userID is obtained from the FB API
    //Do many things

    $response = array(
      'status' => "success",
      'id' => $submission_id
    );
    echo json_encode($response);
  }
?>
```

The JavaScript/Ajax:

```
<script>
  var person = { userID: "", name: ""};

  function logIn() {
            FB.login(function (response) {                
                if (response.status == "connected") {
                    person.userID = response.authResponse.userID;              

                    FB.api('/me?fields=id, name, function (userData) {                        
                        person.name = userData.name;                        

                        $.ajax({
                           url: "login.php",
                           method: "POST",
                           data: person,
                           dataType: 'JSON',
                           success: function (serverResponse) {                               
                               if (serverResponse.status == "success"){                                   
                                   if(serverResponse.id == 0)
                                        window.location = "index.php";
                                   else 
                                        window.location = "details.php?id=" + serverResponse.id ;                                 
                               }
                           }
                        });
                    });
                }
            }, {scope: 'public_profile'})
        }
</script>
```

Where the page `details.php` contains the submission. This also did not work.

Any help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: what on your console.`console.log(serverResponse)` and see what you get. also try `window.location.href`

Comment: @danish-khan-I When I do a console.log(serverResponse.status) or console.log(serverResponse.id) ir prints nothing - since the ajax call does not succeed.